# How do I fix NameError in python? I defined a variable in a for loop and when I try to use it, it gives me a NameErros and says it's not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, variables, scope

This is the code, it reads lc files from a folder that has other folders with the files. In the second for loop I define the variable data which I want to use outside the for loop.

```
Carpeta = "C:/Users/Aguilar/datos de prueba" #directory

for subdirectorio in os.listdir(Carpeta):
    print(subdirectorio)


    for archivo in os.listdir(Carpeta+'/'+subdirectorio):
        if archivo.endswith(".lc"):
            print(archivo)
        
        
            # making data frame from csv file 
       
            data = pd.read_csv(Carpeta+'/'+subdirectorio+'/'+archivo, delimiter=' ', na_values='*********', usecols=[0,2,3], names = ['time', 'magnitude', 'error']) 

            # sorting by first name 
            data.sort_values('time', inplace = True) 

            # dropping ALL duplicate values 
            data.drop_duplicates(subset ="time", keep = False, inplace = True) 

            data = data[data['magnitude'].notna()]

            tess_lc_raw = data.to_records(index=False)
```

The second part of the code where I plan to use the variables is this:

```
lc = [data['time'], data['magnitude'], data['error']]

fs = fts.FeatureSpace(data = ['time', 'magnitude', 'error'])
features, values = fs.extract(*lc)

t = pd.DataFrame(features, values)
print(t)
```

To my understanding the variable is defined in a local scope and that's why it cannot be used globally, I tried using the key word global but it still didn't work. Is there any other way in which I can make it a global variable or use it outside of the for loop?

Comment: Which variable are you having trouble with ? If it is the `data` variable, you may want to initialise it outside of the for-loops.   eg.  `data = []`

Comment: The only variable that needs to be defined in your second block of code is `data`.  If you run both blocks of code in the same file, just as you've shown, then `data` will be defined so long as it ever gets set by the first block of text.  It seems like it will get set so long as the code fines at least one file that ends in `".lc".  I do notice that if you find multiple such files, you're going to be setting `data` multiple times, and losing the results of all but the last iteration of your inner loop.  Also, the end result is `tess_lc_raw` but that doesn't seem to ever be used.

Comment: @ScottC yes that's the variable, I tried it but it gives me a second error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Is the `print(archivo)` line printing anything?  If not, your code is never encountering any `.lc` files, and that's the reason `data` is never defined.

Comment: Well, that's a different problem.  That's going to depend on what you're reading from your file.  `data = data[data['magnitude'].notna()]` is a strange line of code.  Not sure what that's doing.  It sounds to me like `data` ends up being a list, but your second block of code expects it to be a `dict`. - Can you put the error message you're getting in your question, including the complete stack trace?

Comment: @Samwise it doesn't print anything but I removed it and its still the same.

Comment: @CryptoFool The first error message I gots was "NameError: name 'data' is not defined " and now it gives me this message 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str", even If I'm no longer using data = []. I cleared the varibles and now gives me the old error.

Comment: If your code isn't printing anything in the first block, then the second block is not going to work.  The second block of code depends on something having been matched by the first block of code.  if something got matched, then something would have gotten printed.  So it sounds like the code that sets `data` never runs.

Comment: @CryptoFool Oh I see, it only prints the what is on teh first for loop. What do you mean when you say 'something got matched'?

Comment: I mean if the expression `if archivo.endswith(".lc")` ever evaluated to `True` ... if you ever found a filename ending in `".lc"`.

Comment: @CryptoFool Thank you very much! I totally missed that I was testing the code with files ending in txt and not the official files ending in lc. Thank you, for your help and time :)